# Sci-Kit learn model loads incorrectly on unpickling with joblib

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn, joblib

I am trying to achieve model persistence in Sci-Kit Learn using joblib as described in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html. However when I reload my model, I find that all the rows of the models coef_ matrix have been set to zero, except for the first row.

```
joblib.dump(RidgeTfIDF,'/Users/gireesh/Documents/NBC_Chris/modeling/Pickled Models/RidgeESTfIDF11_02_2015_30.pkl')
R2 = joblib.load('/Users/gireesh/Documents/NBC_Chris/modeling/Pickled Models/RidgeESTfIDF11_02_2015_30.pkl')
R2.coef_[1].nonzero()
```

Gives:

```
Out[95]: (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

While
    RidgeTfIDF.coef_[1].nonzero()

Gives

```
Out[96]: (array([      0,       1,       6, ..., 1048563, 1048565, 1048569]),)
```

When I use np.save to save each row of RidgeTfIDF.coef_ in a separate file and then reload from those files, the model works fine. However this is much slower and I would like to fix the joblib problem instead.

Comment: Can you please show a full runnable example? What is `RidgeTfIDF`?

Comment: RidgeTfIDF is a RidgeClassifier: 
'RidgeClassifier(alpha=1, class_weight=None, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=False,
        max_iter=None, normalize=False, solver='auto', tol=0.01)'

with classes_.shape = (343,) and coef_.shape = (343, 1048576)

The classifier was trained on 10k documents with a HashingVectorizer used for generating the feature vectors, so not sure how I can show a full runnable example here?

It must have sthg to do with using HashingVectorizer, because when I pickled a model trained using a TfIdfVectorizer, I did not have any issues unpickling the model.